# Runtime Error - Java Exception occured

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, titanium-android

I am doing an android application using the Appcelerator Titanium. While run the app in the device, i am getting the following error. I don't know what is the problem in my code.

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [13,3502] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,3503] - In ti:/events.js:64,19
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,3503] - Message: Uncaught Error: Java Exception occurred
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,3503] - Source:            handled = this._fireEventToParent(type, data) || handled;
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/events.js:64: Uncaught Error: Java Exception occurred
```

Comment: please share some code or the file where this error happens or the function which is called when you run the app.

Comment: I can't find out the file which is making this error. Because in console it is not showing any details about that one.

Comment: then share the code of alloy.js and index.js file